# Get model when added to collection

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to get a model in a callback when it is added to a collection? I know I can use `listenTo` and then grab the model by the collection's length for index but I suspect there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Collection.add`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) event, which sends the model as the first parameter:

> "add" (model, collection, options) — when a model is added to a collection.

So like:

```
collection.on("change", function(model) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add),then you can get the model:

```
var collection, model;
collection = new Backbone.Collection([
    {
        "name": "m-1"
    },
    {
        "name": "m-2"
    }
]);
model = new Backbone.Model({
    "name": "m-3"
});
collection.on("add", function (model,collection) {
    alert(model.get("name"));
});
collection.add(model);
```